# Database table circular reference between master and child table

Tags: database, database-design

I have two tables

- person
- person_photos

with one-to-many relationship (i.e. each person can have list of photos)

e.g.

```
person {
    person_id number, <<THIS IS PK>>
    person_name varchar,
    other_columns...
}


person_photos {
    person_photo_id number,<<THIS IS PK>>
    person_id number, <<THIS IS FK>>
    photo blob
}
```

I want one of the photo marked as default. Is it ok to have reference to the default photo in master table

i.e.

```
person {
    person_id number,<<THIS IS PK>>
    person_name varchar,
    other_columns...
    default_person_photo_id number <<Reference to child table>>
}
```

This basically creates the circular reference between two table.

Is there any issue with this approach?
Or any other better way of doing it?

Note:

- I can introduce one column in person_photo table to mark which one is default however I primarily introducing this default photo id in master table to avoid getting that information by joinin the photo table
- I can also create a mapping table, but I would like go with that approach only if there is any issue circular design

Answer (score 0):

Part of this depends on what RDBMS you are using.  If you are using one without partial unique indexes (like MySQL for example) then then that is probably the best way you can do it.

On the other hand if you can have partial unique indexes then you can do as follows:

1. Remove `person.default_person_photo_id`
2. Add a boolean `person_photos.is_default` fild
3. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX default_person_photos_idx ON person_photos(person_id) WHERE is_default`

Then you can never have more than one, and if you search for a photo based on a person_id `where is_default` then the index can be used, possibly saving you a join.

So in answer to your question without knowing your rdbms's capabilities, I can't say you there is a better way, and you certainly aren't doing anything wrong.  But for some RDBMSs there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I am using MariaDB

Comment: In that case your approach is probably the best you can do.